# git pull origin master resulted in staging other files that I didn't even modify

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Some observations and questions while working on a `FeatureA` branch.

Following are the initial steps I took:

```
git checkout -b FeatureA
// modify X.c, Y.c, Z.c files
git add <modified files>
git commit -m <msg>
git push -u origin FeatureA // creates a PR for a merge into master
```

Turns out I see some merge conflicts. Also realizes I didn't update the local repo prior to pushing (files I modified was recently modified and pushed by another developer thus I ended up working on an older version)

Then I went on to get the latest changes prior to resolving conflicts

```
git pull origin master
```

Modified the files with conflicts. Done. Runs `git status` to find out there are a whole lot of other files staged (which I didn't modify and possibly was a result of running `git pull origin master`).

```
$ git status
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

File1.c  // file I didn't modify
File2.c  // file I didn't modify
..
...
....
X.c     // file I modified 
Y.c     // file I modified 
Z.c     // file I modified
```

So my merge conflict commit would contain all those files that aren't relevant to the merge conflict itself.

Questions:

1. Is it okay to commit with all these irrelevant files in addition to the files I modified for conflict? I personally don't think so but just curious
2. Is there a way to get those staged files unstaged or perhaps something that allows me to add and commit only the files I modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it okay to commit with all these irrelevant files in addition to the files I modified for conflict?

Yes. In fact, it is necessary. That is what a merge *is*. You said `git pull origin master`. A pull is a merge. A merge brings in the changes from the other branch. That is normal, and it is right — it's what you *want* to do.

> Is there a way to get those staged files unstaged or perhaps something that allows me to add and commit only the files I modified?

No, and you shouldn't. And you should stop wanting to. All is well. Don't worry; when you make your pull request, the only changes that will appear as part of the pull request will be yours.

Comment: so basically I should proceed with making a commit after solving merge conflicts and the PR would show the only files I modified?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I just said!  If I find some time later I'll expand my answer to explain why. But I wanted to set your mind at rest immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Also how come I don't see any of the files that got pulled from `origin/master` up on the remote as a part of the merge commit? That's exactly what I wanted but out of curiosity....

Comment: In a nutshell, it's because they are in that state in master and and in that very same state (now) in your branch, so in that regard there is nothing to merge. As I say, if I get more time, I'll describe this in more detail. Or you could just read my essay on what a merge is: https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/